# React-BootStrap Pagination V1 not showing page numbers

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

For a few years we have been using **React Bootstrap v0.0.31** in which we are using `Pagination` component. Below is the syntax:

```
<Pagination
  className="abc className"
  prev={this.renderBackPage()}
  next={this.renderNextPage()}
  first={this.renderFirstButton()}
  last={this.renderLastButton()}
  ellipsis
  boundaryLinks
  items={this.props.pages}
  maxButtons={3}
  activePage={activePageToSet}
  onSelect={this.handlePageSelect}
/>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQdbl.png)

After upgrading to V1 version
https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/pagination/

Do I need to write my own pagination logic to handle the page numbers to be shown? Previously just passing the pages to the component worked.

Now I need to generate page numbers with an ellipsis as shown in the above screenshot.
Could someone point me to the right direction of how to achieve this?